# Using the lightest carriage to move n objects in specific days

Tags: algorithm

I have to solve this problem but I can't think of any algorithm for it . Any help is appreciated :)

Problem : we want to move n objects with different weights to another location using a carriage and we have limited days to do so . we can only use the carriage once a day and because it costs a lot we want to choose a carriage that can move all of our product in the given days but pay the minimum amount for it so the objective is to choose a carriage with the least capacity that will do the job ( the price we have to pay for the carriage increases greatly as the capacity goes higher ) . Also the items should be moved according to their weight and the smallest items go first .

the given data : n items , i'th object wights Wi , d days
wanted : c which shows the minimum capacity for our chosen carriage

```
Example :
10 items
weights : 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
5 days

answer : 15
day 1 -> 1,2,3,4
day 2 -> 5,6
day 3 -> 7,8
day 4 -> 9
day 5 -> 10
```

Comment: Start with smallest possible carriage that might work (c = (sum Wi) / d). Use a variant of [bin packing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem#:~:text=In%20the%20bin%20packing%20problem,a%20combinatorial%20NP%2Dhard%20problem.) to fit the items into days of size c. Increase size of carriage until it works. Or something like that.

Comment: The solution in the example is not the optimum. For example by swapping 6 and 7 you get a better one.

Comment: In fact even the theoretical minimum of 11 can be achieved (1,10), (2,9), (3,8), (4,7), (5,6).

Comment: @Henry the order in which the items will be send shouldnt change , which means we cant send the first item with the last one or 5 with 7 without having 6 in the package as well .

Answer (score 1):

To solve this problem efficiently, you should do binary search. You can do binary search on carriage and check for which minimum value you can do that. You can see my C++ solution below for better understanding.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
//#include <ext/pb_ds/tree_policy.hpp>
//#include <ext/pb_ds/assoc_container.hpp>
using namespace std;
//using namespace __gnu_pbds;
typedef long long ll;
typedef unsigned long long ull;
typedef pair<ll,ll> pll;
typedef pair<int,int> pii;
//typedef tree<ll,null_type,less<ll>,rb_tree_tag,tree_order_statistics_node_update>ordered_set;

#define fread           freopen("input.txt","r",stdin)
#define fwrite          freopen("output.txt","w",stdout)
#define eb              emplace_back
#define em              emplace
#define pb              push_back
#define Mp              make_pair
#define ff              first
#define ss              second
#define all(a)          a.begin(),a.end()
#define Unique(a)       sort(all(a)),a.erase(unique(all(a)),a.end())
#define FastRead        ios_base::sync_with_stdio(0);cin.tie(0);
#define memo(ara,val)   memset(ara,val,sizeof(ara))
#define II              ( { int a ; read(a) ; a; } )
#define LL              ( { ll a ; read(a) ; a; } )
#define DD              ({double a; scanf("%lf", &a); a;})
#define rep(i,n)        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
#define rep1(i,n)       for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
#define rrep(i,a,n)     for(int i=a;i<=n;i++)
#define per(i,n,a)      for(int i=n;i>=a;i--)
#define pf(n)           printf("%lld",n)
#define pfi(n)          printf("%d",n)
#define sp              printf(" ")
#define ln              printf("\n")
#define sc(x)           scanf("%lld",&x)
#define scw(x)          scanf("%I64d",&x)
#define sci(x)          scanf("%d",&x)
#define sc2(x,y)        scanf("%lld %lld",&x,&y)
#define sc3(x,y,z)      scanf("%lld %lld %lld",&x,&y,&z)
#define Found(a, b)     a.find(b) != a.end()
// bool operator< (const node& sx) const { return sx.val < val; }
//set<ll,greater<ll> >st;
//priority_queue<ll , vector<ll> , greater<ll> >
template<class T>inline bool read(T &x){ int c=getchar();int sgn=1;
  while(~c&&c<'0'|c>'9'){if(c=='-')sgn=-1;c=getchar();}
  for(x=0; ~c&&'0'<=c&&c<='9'; c=getchar())x=x*10+c-'0';x*=sgn;return ~c;
}
const ll N = 200005;
const ll MOD = 1e9+7;
ll ara[N], d, n;
bool check(ll carriageCapacity) {
     ll days = 1;
     ll s = 0;
     bool f = true;
     rep1(i, n) {
        s += ara[i];
        if(s > carriageCapacity) {
            days += 1;
            s = ara[i];
        }
     }
     if(days > d) f = false;
     return f;
}

int main(){

     //fread;
     //fwrite;
    n = LL;
    ll sum  = 0;
    rep1(i,n) {
       ara[i] = LL;
       sum += ara[i];
    }
    d = LL;
    ll lo = ara[n], hi = sum, ans;
    while(lo <= hi) {
        ll mid = (lo + hi) >> 1;
        if(check(mid)) {
            hi = mid - 1;
            ans = mid;
        }
        else {
            lo = mid + 1;
        }
    }
    cout << ans << endl;

}
```

Comment: Since the question just mentions "algorithm", you don't need to provide a complicated implementation in any language

Comment: I thought the implementation might help to understand the algorithm better, maybe I was wrong. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Python solution would look like this.
Using binary search to find the container size that will satisfy the given condition. Complexity of this solution would be O(n * log n)

```
def shipWithinDays(weights: List[int], D: int) -> int:
    def feasible(capacity) -> bool:
        days = 1
        total = 0
        for weight in weights:
            total += weight
            if total > capacity:  # too heavy, wait for the next day
                total = weight
                days += 1
                if days > D:  # cannot ship within D days
                    return False
        return True

    left, right = max(weights), sum(weights)
    while left < right:
        mid = left + (right - left) // 2
        if feasible(mid):
            right = mid
        else:
            left = mid + 1
    return left
```